# Issues upgrading android app in market

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded an android application in google market place
Now i want to add some features in the build and upgrade the version but i am not able to do so since when i try to create a signed appplication with the same keystore i get the error : the password is incorrect or the keystore is tampered and hence i am not able to sighn the application with the same keystore.

So now i thought of unpublishing the application and uploading the new version of this application as a new application now i get the error that the package name of the application already exists.

Please guide me seriously confused the keystore is the same one and the password i am entering is also the same i even stored it in a mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways:

1. Remember the correct password.
2. **OR** Change the package declaration. (i.e if current is `my.package` change it to `your.package` or whatever)

Comment: **More in 2nd Point:** To upload brand new application, take care while naming Package, it must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem before and it was irritating. Because you can't remove the application from the market. Anyway, if the error message shows `The password is incorrect or the keystore is tampered`, Most probably it's an incorrect password if it's the similar keystore. (Never forget the keystore password if you're gonna spend time upgrading it.)

If you are unable to remember the password, then you will have to upload another application with a different package name. Create a new keystore for that too.

What I do is I record down my keystore passwords so I do not forget and have to upload new applications and keystores again.

Cheers